# SQLite Android INNER JOIN sqlite.SQLiteException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

This is the query I am trying to run that will do a join on two tables in my DB

```
Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("SELECT Media.Name, Media.Location, Game.Name, Game.Format " +
                               "FROM Media INNER JOIN Game " +
                               "On Media._id = Game.MediaId",
                               null);
return cur
```

It keeps flagging this error but everything seems to be correct??

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
near "INNER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Media.Name, Medi....
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide both tables schema.

Comment: Its from a pre built DB that im reading from, so all i do is open the database.

Comment: That is OK, but we need to know more about the tables in order to help you figuring out what is wrong with the join.